# How do I use the `imem` memory stream as source for the .NET VLC wrapper?

Tags: c#, vlc, memorystream

The input receives audio or video in any format, and the output should be a wave. I decided to use the volcano wrapper for .NET. At this point I realized this is realized with a file as source. The problem is that I have a byte array as source.

After reading forums I've come to the conclusion that it is necessary to use the module `imem`, but I have difficulties with it.

How do I properly use `imem` as a data source instead of the file transfer stream?

Answer (score 0):

Right now it's not possible to do that from C#. Mainly because you need to specify --imem-get and --imem-release handler addresses as strings and thers no way of getting those from C# (well, you can get a pointer via GCHandle, but it crashes when VLC tries to call it).

Walkaround for this would be either:

- Write C API that implements get and release handlers. Theres a good forum post [here](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=93842) and [here](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=85451)
- Save data to hard drive and load that to VLC